# How can I set up a web server for reverse proxy having websockets and socket.io working normally?

Tags: web-server, reverse-proxy, lighttpd, node.js

I have a VPS currently hosting **`node.js`** web apps and one site. However I'm currently using custom ports for the apps.

I'd like to simply give each its custom domain and so for more sites, that would mean they all would go to port 80 by default.

As I understand I need to use a reverse proxy, but I want to make sure that:

- Web Sockets
- Socket.io

Will work normally. Soon I will have to mount:

- Drupal
- Simple Rails/Sinatra tests

Are Apache, lighttpd or nginx the *best* options? Are there any easy `node.js` recommended and well documented options?

At the momment, my best option would be `lighttpd` on top

Comment: lighttpd 1.4.x (the current stable series) does not support bidirectional connections, i.e. no WebSockets.

Comment: What about using HAProxy, @Stefan ?

Comment: HAProxy is a fine tool to route/balance to other HTTP backends and should work well with WebSockets